# Are malloc memory pages attributes set to cacheable or non-cacheable?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When we use malloc and access memory, the physical pages being given for this address space has what kind of page attributes, are they cacheable or non-cacheable pages ?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary memory -- whether for user-space or kernel -- is pretty much always marked cacheable. Otherwise, using that memory would entail a huge performance hit.

Generally speaking, the only time you want memory to be marked non-cacheable is when the memory is actually part of an external device (i.e. a device other than a memory chip): for example, a PCI device BAR region used to implement device control registers.

Caching is good for performance since reading and writing the cache is usually *much* faster than reading and writing the underlying RAM. And the caching can "bundle up" reads and writes so that those operations on the RAM chip are done significantly less often. The downside is that by using it you generally give up exact control over the reading and writing of the RAM.

The main RAM usually gets read and written at "random" times as determined by the cache controller, and it typically gets read and written in large blocks called "cache lines" -- blocks of 32-, 64- or 128-bytes at a time. When you write a value to cached memory, that value may not get written to the actual RAM chip until some indeterminate later time (if ever: it might get overwritten before it ever gets transferred out of the cache). This is of course all hidden you as a user of the memory -- you don't generally even need to be aware of it.

But if the memory being written to is a control register -- setting some mode or characteristic of a device for example -- then you want the value of that register to be set exactly when you write to it not at some indeterminate later time, and you don't want the write to that register to affect any other registers that may be located near to it in the address space.

Likewise, if you read the value of a status register, it might be "volatile": i.e. its value might change with two consecutive reads of the same register so you don't want the value cached. And reading a register might have side-effects, so you only want explicit reads to access it.